Incorporating stomp switch into fuzz pedal
My friend asked me to design a fuzz pedal for him, so I based my design on this project: https://www.electrosmash.com/germanium-fuzz
Their schematic is as follows:

What I am confused about is their Jack connectors as I don't see how they are tied to ground. I also find the stomp switch placement a bit strange as I found another website that shows the connections a bit differently.
Here is the website: https://fuzzcentral.ssguitar.com/faq.php , followed by their schematic:

Is their schematic good to reference off of? I wanted to fit the project in the same enclosure but add input bias to the circuit before Q1 and Q2, which can be seen below:

UPDATE: Here is my attempt at fixing the schematic, I decided to keep the jumpers and removed +9V_A entirely (turns out that is the GND of the battery) and changed the jack symbols and tried to establish proper connections.



"I also find the stomp switch placement a bit strange as I found another website that shows the connections a bit differently." - The switch looks to be wired the same way in both. What's confusing is that one shows a schematic representation of the switch while the other shows a physical representation of the switch.

@Finbarr Yeah both schematics are confusing, the stomp switch is the actual part rather than a symbol I can see what they were trying to do but it looks rather out of place compared to the other parts.

It is out of place, but given the red lines on the second diagram I'm guessing someone has modified the original.

One of the problems is that a lot of these projects are done by people who don't have a background in electronics, so they might not know that ground and battery negative are not the same thing.
These boxes are using PNP transistors, so the power supply polarity is reversed from the more commonly seen NPN circuits. The way they should be drawn is with the battery positive as ground, and what they have as ground marked -9 V. Because if you look at the circuit it's just a couple of common emitter amplifiers, and if you switched them to NPN you would normally see the emitters going to ground. If you look at schematics from the 1960s when PNP transistors were the norm, you'll usually see the supplies drawn with positive as ground and the supply voltage shown as negative.
So what you're seeing is that the jacks are "grounded" by being connected to the battery positive. Whatever you're connecting to doesn't care if you use the positive or negative as ground, as long as there's no DC voltage between tip and ring.
I'm not sure what's going on with the first schematic, it looks like the signals are connected to the jack ring instead of tip, possibly because of how they have the jack switch circuit wired. I'm not sure how well this would work with a long cable, the signal would be on the shield instead of inner conductor so should be more susceptible to noise.

Thank you for the detailed explanation. So in the case of my schematic, having the +9V connected to the emitter and and GND to the collector? Also, how can I reconfigure the first circuit to have the signal on the inner conductor? A drawing of this would really be appreciated.

@dreece2498 The second schematic (fuzzcentral) shows one way to do it, but it uses a different kind of jack, one where the circuit is closed between the ring and switched contact when the cable is plugged in.

I'm assuming there using a shorting jack then? I'm probably better off just referring to the one on fuzzcentral then.

@dreece2498 One of the jacks needs to switch the battery into the circuit, typically whichever side of it is being used as ground since the jack needs ground for the audio too. There are different ways of doing that. You can look at the jacks and switching as separate from the effects circuit, you can pick which way you want to do the jacks and then connect that to whichever effects circuit you want. So for example you could take the fuzz circuit from the first schematic and use it with the jacks from the second.

The jack they use in the first schematic is the NMJ6HCD2, are shunt jacks available in through-hole mounting styles? I can only seem to find one that would be connected via soldering wires onto it.

The NMJ6HCD2 IS through-hole mounted.

@dreece2498 Okay, then they haven't drawn it correctly, it should have 6 pins. You would want the NMJ6HCD2-SM for Shield Make. Then +9V_A would be connected to Shield, +9V_B to Shield Make (or the other way around, not sure it matters) and the input would be Tip. Tip Shunt could be connected to ground so you don't get hum when the cord is unplugged. I'll try to draw up a schematic later.

@Finbarr, yes it is through hole I just wanted to be sure I was using the right connector, as I don't have any experience designing pedals.

@Godjihyo  Thanks for the clarification.

@dreece2498 Yes, that connector will work fine, you don't need the switching functionality so just ignore the three extra pins.

@Finbarr Do the jacks need one of the pins tied to ground? With regards to the first schematic it seems that their only using pins to connect to the stomp switch and battery, I know you said ignore the three extra pins but I want to be sure I don't have to reconfigure one of the pins I'm already using.

Both schematics use the input connector in the same way, it's just impossible to tell with the wrong symbol.  Tip to pin 1, ring to pin 2, sleeve to pin 3.

@GodJihyo, See my updated schematic on this post, attempted to fix the faulty jack symbols and establish proper connections.

There's a fundamental difference between the first two designs, but they're so badly and confusingly drawn that it's very hard to tell.
The second diagram uses the input jack to switch power to the circuit on and off. It uses a stereo (aka TRS) jack socket but it expects a mono jack plug to be inserted, which is what you'd expect a guitar lead to have on the end. When it's plugged in, the sleeve and ring terminals on the socket are connected together by the sleeve of the jack plug, and this connects the battery positive to what they have labelled as ground and applies power to the circuit. The footswitch uses two of the three poles to switch the circuit in or out of the signal path, and uses the third pole to light the LED to indicate that the circuit is active in the signal path. With this circuit you need to remember to unplug the input jack when you finish, which you'd probably do anyway when packing up.
The first one does the same trick with the input jack, but this is difficult to understand because they've used the wrong symbol for J1 - the symbol they've used shows a mono jack socket with a switch contact that's normally connected to the tip pin but contact is broken when the jack is inserted. But more significantly, the power from the battery is also routed through the footswitch, so switching the circuit out of the signal path also turns it off. The advantage is obviously that it saves power when you switch it out of the signal path, and you don't need to unplug the input jack when you finish using it, which may be useful if it's on a board connected to other pedals. But the disadvantage is that this can cause a transient on the output as C3 charges up and a pronounced "thump" when switched on and off while playing, which could be rather undesirable.
I'd go with the second circuit but it's really a matter of preference and just how audible that thump gets.

I think you did a great job of explaining it, and yes you are correct both schematics are very poorly drawn, part of my intention was to make a better fuzz pedal schematic but due to my lack of experience with guitar pedals I was having a difficult time understanding how the connections worked in regards to the stomp switch.
